# How to calculate 32 bit bitmap to set parameters in bluetooth module

Tags: bitmap, bluetooth

I'm developing device with RN4020 bluetooth module on it. In [user's guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005191B.pdf) (page 29) is a table of bitmap values to set parameters but I just can't get my head around it. What if, for example, I want to set three parameters: 0x40000000, 0x10000000 and 0x02000000. What is the final bitmap value to send to the module and how do I calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Each hex number from that table, when converted to binary, has only one '1' and 31 '0's so in my example:

```
40000000h = ‭01000000000000000000000000000000‬b
10000000h = ‭00010000000000000000000000000000‬b
02000000h = ‭00000010000000000000000000000000‬b
```

So number I'm looking for is 01010010000000000000000000000000‬b which is 52000000h